# How can i solve this problem in react.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Black@DESKTOP-N04CDRI MINGW64 /c/web devlopment/react-chat-application/chat-application (master)
$ npm start

> chat-application@0.1.0 start C:\web devlopment\react-chat-application\chat-application
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.js
Searched in: C:\web devlopment\react-chat-application\chat-application\src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! chat-application@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the chat-application@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Black\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-29T15_56_51_774Z-debug.log

Black@DESKTOP-N04CDRI MINGW64 /c/web devlopment/react-chat-application/chat-application (master)
$

Comment: Look in your `src` folder. Is there an `index.js` file inside?

Comment: Please update your post [just a little](/help/how-to-ask) so that your title summarizes your problem, and your post actually has an explanation of your situation (including what _you_ think is wrong and what you tried already based on that assumption) and crucially, contains a question. With any code or logs you're showing marked up with proper code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you may have deleted `index.js` file or renamed it.if you are using `react-create-app` pipeline then you can't rename that or remove this file so make sure it's present in your src folder inside project dir and if you are using git then run `git status` it will tell you what you had changed.

Answer (score 0):

**index.html has been moved/removed from the /public directory**

Does your project have an index.js file in the public directory?

If not you can get the one that [Create React App uses here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template/template/src/index.js)